# How to apply the same row color when the row is expanded for a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a table with a striped rows when I expand the row the data will be displayed but when I expand the row the same background color is not applying to my expanded data instead it's considering as a next row apply the alternate color. How do I apply the same parent color to the expanded row

Down below is the expand functionality

```
    <td>
     <USBButton
         type="button"
         iconColor="default"
         ariaLabel={"expand"} 
         addClasses={"expandButton"}
         id={'expand-collapse_btn-${1}'} 
         name={"expandcollapse"}
         variant="naked"
         size="small"
         handleclick={(e) -> onExpandHandler (i)}>
      {expandedRows.includes(i) ? (
         <USBIconChevronlp />
           ) : (
         <USBIconChevronDown />
      }}
    </USBButton>
  </td>
```

Down below is the code where I am trying to display expanded data

```
    <tr key={i}
      className={Itable-row-default table-row-${i}}>
     <td colspan={columnData.length + 1}>
        {dataExpand[i]}
     </td>
    </tr>
```

Down below is the css

```
    tr{
        &:nth-child(odd) {
    background: gray;
    }
     &:nth-child(even) {
    background: white;
    }
  }
```

How do I solve this

`onExpandHandler()`

```
    const onExpandHandler = (i) => {

const currentExpandedRows = expandedRows;

const isRowExpanded = currentExpandedRows.includes(i)

const newExpanded Rows = isRowExpanded ?  currentExpandedRows.filter ((index) => index !== i): currentExpandedRows.concat(i);
setExpandedRows (newExpandedRows);
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since your background coloring will NOT depend on the even/odd index information, you should simply use another approach for the styling.

What I would do personally is use CSS classes to identify the initial even/odd rows and when a row get extended give its children the same class.

You didnt share the 'expand' code so I do not really know how you could do that but something like that:

```
<tr
  key={i}
  className={`Itable-row-default table-row-${i} ${i%2 === 0 ? 'table-white' : 'table-grey'}` }
>
  <td colspan={columnData.length + 1}>
    {dataExpand[i]}
  </td>
</tr>
```

And the associated css

```
tr {
  &.table-gray {
    background: gray;
  }
  &.table-white {
    background: white;
  }
```

}

Depending on the 'onExpandHandler' method & the format of your initial model this might need some adaptations though :)

(oh and you should favor screenshots for images :p)

Comment: I have updated my question. I have tried above code but the same issue when I expand any row its considering the expanded as a new row and the whole table color changes